# Is it possible to use validators on return values of array (not form)?

Tags: arrays, angular, validation

I have created a function which extracts emails from given text.
Now I want to validate the extracted emais with already existing validators.
But I am not quite sure if this is possible on return values of a string array.

Function I use to extract emails from text:

```
//Variables
emailText: string;
emailArray: string[];

getEmailAddressFromText():string [] {
    let regexToExtractEmails= /(?:[a-z0-9+!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/gi;
     return this.emailArray= this.emailText.match(regexToExtractEmails);
  
}
```

HTML-Code for text area and display result

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                 <textarea class="email-text-input"
                                           matInput
                                           placeholder="placeholder="Add E-Mail""
                                           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                           [(ngModel)]="emailText"
                                           (keyup.enter)="getEmailAddressFromText()"
                                           (keyup.enter)="clearInput()"
                                 > </textarea>

                            </mat-form-field>

                                <ul *ngFor="let email of emailArray">
                                    <ul >Email: {{email}} </ul>
                                </ul>
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to use already existing Validators on return values of a string array which are not defined as form fields.

How can this be done or is there a better way?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Could you share your existing validators? What should the validators do? Like just throw errors on each individual invalid email? Validate the entire list of emails? Filter out invalid emails and only present valid emails? What should happens. Anyway, the implementation would be quite straight forward. Create a new form (or add a control to a existing one), attach the validators that you wish and with `patchValue` on the control, assign `this.emailArray` to the control.value.

Comment: The validators check whether it is a valid company email:  Validators.pattern(this.validDomain). I want to check each individual email, apply color red when it is invalid and green when its valid. The User can then decide whether to add this email to existing form or not

Comment: Hello @Joosep.P how can I assign the return values of the array to the controls? As I want to use the validators on each return value not the whole array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing how you're pretty good with regex. I might suggest an pure pipe to check each email validity. If it's not valid color is red, if valid it's green.

```html
<ul *ngFor="let email of emailArray">
  <li
    [ngClass]="{
      'text-red': !(email | validEmail),
      'text-green': (email | validEmail)
    }"
  >
    Email: {{ email }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  emailText = 'test@.com, gibberih@hotmail.com, 123@123.com';
emailArray: RegExpMatchArray;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmailAddressFromText();
  }

  getEmailAddressFromText() {
    let regexToExtractEmails =
      /(?:[a-z0-9+!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/gi;
    this.emailArray = this.emailText.match(regexToExtractEmails);
    console.log(this.emailArray)
  }
}

@Pipe({name: 'validEmail'})
export class ValidEmailPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(email: string): boolean {
    const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;
    console.log('Is email valid: ', EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email))
    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email)
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-12-e4dwh1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html